# web2py: writing to session variables in python

Tags: python, session, variables, web2py

I've been messing around with web2py. I used session variables to give certain variables a global scope. However, I am only able to read data from these variables, and I'm not able to overwrite their current value. This is my code:

```
session.ROWS= 10

def row_column():
    print session.ROWS
    session.ROWS = session.ROWS+1
    print session.ROWS
```

The output that i get on calling row_column multiple times(i call it via AJAX) :

```
10
11
10
11
```

Any clue on how to write to a session variable? I want the output to be:

```
10
11
11
12
12
13
```

and so on...

Comment: Are your sessions stored in files, the database, or cookies? Does your code call `session.forget()` anywhere? How (and how rapidly) are you making the multiple Ajax calls?

Comment: @Anthony: i use the web2py default session behaviour, where variables are treated like global variables. I retrieved the basic syntax from the web2py tutorial http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services?search=session . I do not call session.forget(). I give atleast 10-15s between calls.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the problem at first -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call the `row_columns` action, the entire controller is executed. At the top level of the controller, you have:

```
session.ROWS = 10
```

So, you are resetting `session.ROWS` to 10 on every request. If you need to initialize it somewhere, you can instead do:

```
if not session.ROWS:
    session.ROWS = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the same session without a page refresh. I'm sure you can monkey with how the session is stored.  Open the file or the db record and change the data and save it.

This post indicates how to do it.
[web2py insert value into session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527199/web2py-insert-value-into-session)

Comment: By default, the session is stored in a file on the server, so you do not need a page refresh to update it. You should be able to update it with an Ajax request.